# Elastic Search PHP Client Date Range Query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have this code what executes an query. 
I am using the official php elastic search library.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

The field "Tijdsperiode" is in this format :     ( 2016-01-30 00:00:00 ) ( YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS )

```
  $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'match_all' => [],
        'filter' => [
          'range' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'gte' => '2016-01-30 01:00:00',
              'lte' => '2016-01-30 08:00:00'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $response = $client->search($params);

  var_dump($response);
```

I just wonder what the format need to be to get results between the 2 dates.

When i do this :

```
 $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
          'match_all' => [],
        ],
    ],
  ];
```

It's working fine but i need the results between the 2 dates!

I also tried this but with no result :

```
  $json = '{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                  "Tijdsperiode": {
                    "gt": "2016-01-30 07:00:00",
                    "lt":  "2016-01-30 09:00:00"
                  }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';

  $client = ckan_graphmapper_client();

  $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'body' => $json
  ];

  $response = $client->search($params);
```

I also tried it with a mapping :

```
  $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'size' => $size,
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        "match_all" => [],
        'filter' => [
          'range' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'gte' => '2016-01-30 01:00:00',
              'lte' => '2016-01-30 08:00:00'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'mappings' => [
        '_default_' => [
          'properties' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'type' => 'date',
              'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

How to do the right syntax for choosing between 2 dates?. Both string formats ( 2016-01-30 00:00:00 ) ( YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS )

Thanks!

Comment: which date format you set in mappings?

Comment: Hi Veerendra, I Added my type but it's still not working.. Any ideas?

Comment: 'datetime' => [
                         'type' => 'date',
                       'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                       ]

Comment: format also you need to give.for more formats check in elasticsearch

Comment: Are you paasing query with mappings..

Comment: what is the output when you searching inbetween two dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my import of data was not mapping the correct way. 
The date field was recognised as a string value.

When i finnaly had the correct mapping in elastic i could do this query :

```
 $query = [
    'query' => [
      'filtered' => [
        'query' => [
          'match_all' => []
        ],
        'filter' => [
          'range' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'gte' => $start,
              'lte' => $end
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```